# Compare Dates in a column corresponding to Changes in an other row

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have a large sample of medical data I need to try and analyze patterns in Excel worksheet.
I also put them up in a database in MS ACCESS to do my first filters and stuff.

I have the infos of patients, with tests results(POS or NEG), dates of the sample.

I need to be able to check for each patients when the results change from POS to NEG and from NEG to POS
and compare the dates of those two samples.

So far I was doing it manually which isn't viable for my sample.
I was trying to do something in SQL, but that didn't work out for me.
I also am trying to do some VBA or Excel formulas but I admit I'm getting kind of stumped.

I know I should do some for each cell loop or something but I really am lost.

I already grouped each patients info together using sub-totals and stuff.

Your help or at least pointers would be greatly appreciated :D

Here's an example of my data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP2GO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a formula like this, that in case the name is the same as the row before and the POS/NEG is different from the row before gives you the number of days in between, blank otherwise:

[image]

Of course it will give you an error if you try to use it on the 1st line, just enter it in the 2nd line and copy/paste in all the rest.

This should give you the basis for the rest of your analysis.

Comment: Oh my god, that works great. Can’t believe I was butting my head against that when such a clear formula did the trick :). Thank you so much.